# Replace <br/> with comma in HTML

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is my HTML code:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://keyes.findbuyers.com/search_details/hGdxEaI0bAO568MBDtCCfvjtY74dYmJKhIeURpGbbtxBQvzbNLwrKJL381lFafq10-YkJ58zGW6Lc8fpOny7fW/customerservice@keyes.com">
999 SW 1st Ave
<br/>
Miami, FL 33130
</a>
```

When I print the address it is displaying it on two lines in the console:

```
999 SW 1st Ave
Miami, FL 33130
```

I want to print the address like this:

```
999 SW 1st Ave, Miami, FL 33130
```

How can I do that?

Comment: could you add what you have tried (your code to print address)  in the question?

Comment: String1= "9600 SW 122nd Ave, Miami, FL 33186"           List<WebElement> address=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[2]/p/a"));
String2 addr=address.get(0).getText();                   System.out.println("recent address is: "+addr);

Comment: @srinuvasareddymarri, show your `Java` + `Selnium` code

Comment: now i have to compare String1 and String2

Comment: Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20372433/5443971

Comment: You just replace the newline in the string with ", ". You need to google this and find the code. This has been answered a million times on the web already.

Answer (score 0):

When you print on console an new line is indicated by special character `'\r'` or `'\n'` or `'\r\n'` (depending on OS).

The same new line will not work in browser, however if you want to retain new line in browser either you can enclose your text in a `<pre>` tag or you can replace `'\r\n'` with a `<br>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

[`<Br/>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) tag is to mark break line, so it's normal that the address is split in two lines, in order to print it in one line get rid of this tag.

But if you want to get your address in one line using Java, you may update your line as follow:

```
...
String addr=address.get(0).getText().replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)+", ",");
```

Both windows and Unix carriage return character are covered.

Comment: Due to <Br/> address is printing in two lines now i want to print in One line how can i write the code for this

Comment: @srinuvasareddymarri I will update my answer soon, but consider updating your question with all information.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the tag `<br/>`

Comment: @srinuvasareddymarri refer hear http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199740/webdriver-remove-element-from-page